# Interaction between user controls

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 2 usercontrols in a wpf application. In my user control A, when I click on a button it will grab the text inside a textbox from usercontrol B. How do I access the text in the textbox when i click on the button in A?

```
  public partial class UserControlB : UserControl
  {
      public string TextBoxText { get { return this.TextBoxB.Text; } }
  }
```

Then in usercontrol A, when i click the button

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        String s = UserControlB.TextBoxText ;

    }
```

Comment: If the controls are accessible to each other (check modifiers), use their objects to get the value. If the objects are not accessible, try searching for the target control.

Comment: how do we go about checking the modifiers?

Comment: I meant, check if the controls in question are "public" or "private/protected". If "public", you can directly access the objects.

Answer (score 2):

Add a property in B, returning the text of the TextBox:

```
public class UserControlB
{
    public string TextBoxText { get { return this.TextBox1.Text; } }
}
```

Find the instance of the UserControl B in your xaml, then call the property as follows:

```
string txt = this.UserControlB.TextBoxText;
```

Comment: i did that in my usercontrolB but on the usercontrolA side, i cannot access the textbox from the C# code. it says an object reference is needed for the non static field method or property

Comment: Seems like mix-up of static and non-static fields. Code please!

Comment: code as edited. Other than the segment above, is there anything else i need to add?

Comment: @edelweiss As I mentioned, you have to find the instance of UserControlB instead of using UserControlB (as a type) directly.

Comment: @ojlovecd how do i find my instance of UserControlB?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a short answer, but i would think that a FindControl("textboxName') should work.

string text = userControlB.FindControl("textbox")

Answer (score 0):

In your question you aren't correctly referencing your `UserControlB`

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)     
{
    String s = UserControlB.TextBoxText ;      
}
```

Here you are looking at the *class* called `UserControlB`, not an object or an *instance* of `UserControlB`.  In other words, you're not specifying *which* `UserControlB` you want to look at.  If you had five `UserControlB` on your screen, how does the button know which one to use?

Read [Classes and Objects](http://www.willamette.edu/~gorr/classes/cs231/lectures/chp1.htm) to learn about the difference between Classes (like `UserControlB`) and Objects (items that you can reference and use in your program).

The `UserControlB` that you have on your page or view should have a `Name` if you want to use it. Once you find the name, you can reference it like this:

```
// inside the control which contains your UserControlB
public MainPage()
{
    // find it according to its Name property
    UserControlB theOneIWantToUse = this.UserControlB_1;

    // once you identify it, you can get the Text value from it
    String s = theOneIWantToUse.Text;
}
```

Comment: You might have an instance named the same as its type, in which case I'm off target, but that is bad bad bad!

Comment: sorry what does UserControlB_1 refer to? the name of the usercontrolB?

Comment: @edelweiss Yes, whatever the `Name` property of the control is set to.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

In UserControl A,

> private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
>      {
>
> ```
>    MainWindow rootWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow;
>    String s = (String)rootWindow.B.TextBoxB.text;
> ```
>
> }

Comment: B is the name of the second UserControl, like you said in your question. Likewise, TextBoxB is the TextBox in UserControl B that you want to read from UserControl A.