# Sharing data between 2 usercontrols in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have usercontrol lets say UA with a textbox in it. Now i want to access the value in the textbox in the codebehind of another usercontrol, let says UB
Both the usercontrols are on a tab. What is the efficient way to do this?

Comment: Use the DataContext to do that. It's by far the most efficient of doing it.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I am new to WPF. I have tried setting a DataContext in usercontrol B to a view model. Now how to access the view model in user control A

Comment: Can some body please help me?. How do i share ViewModel or datacontext between the user controls on the same tab? In the target user control, i want to use the source text box value in code behind. I dont want to bind it to another control

Answer (score 0):

Provide both UserControls with a dependency property that the other can bind to or

Some xaml:

```
<local:Uc1 x:Name="uc1" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=uc2, Path=Thing}" />
<local:Uc2 x:Name="uc2" />
```

This can be done in code as well.

or bind both UserControls to the same ViewModel.

also look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060040/interaction-between-user-controls) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19514617/how-to-pass-value-in-usercontrol-in-wpf)

**Updated Answer**

Defining custom Dependency Property in MainWindow.cs

```
public string Prop
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(PropProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PropProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Prop.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PropProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Prop", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata("Hello!!"));
```

Now just bind this dp to your two user control
UserControl 1

```
 <Grid>
    <TextBox Height="25" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window},Path=Prop, 
        Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="65"/>
</Grid>
```

UserControl 2

```
 <Grid>
    <TextBox Height="25" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window},Path=Prop, 
        Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="65"/>
</Grid>
```

This is just an example to get going with custom dp`s.

Comment: The dependency property option is much better, and this answer would be better served by providing an example of that as opposed to binding the DataContext (which is generally a bad idea).

Comment: Abhinav, can u provide some code sample. i am am trying couple of days but coudnt get it right. I want a text box value in controlA to be accessed in another ControlB's code behind. That is in contolB button click, i want to access control A text box

Comment: @ravishanker Hello I have updated the code...hav a look