# Share DataContext between MainWindows and UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, datacontext

I wonder if it is possible to shared a datacontext between a Windows and is UserControl in C#/WPF.

I have a main windows like this (not finished):

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject"
        xmlns:v="clr-namespace:MyProject.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MyProject" >
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel/>        
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <v:GenerateView/>
        <v:ReadView/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainViewModel.cs:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    #region Properties
    #endregion

    #region Fields
    #endregion

    #region Constructor
    public MainViewModel()
        : base()
    {
    }
    #endregion

    #region Methods
    #endregion

    #region Commands
    #endregion
}
```

Depending on a future parameter, I will display my view GenerateView or ReadView. Actually I'm developing the UserControl GenerateView, but I wonder if I can use the same Datacontext.

According to [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22573295/sharing-data-between-2-usercontrols-in-wpf), I started by this :

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.Views.GenerateView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject.Views"
         xmlns:p="clr-namespace:MyProject.Properties"
         xmlns:MyProject="clr-namespace:MyProject" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
         DataContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type MyProject:MainWindow}}}">
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

But It doesn't work, when I try to access Datacontext in `GenerateView`, It is null.

Edit:

I forgot a part of my code:

```
public partial class GenerateView : UserControl
{
    private MainViewModel Context
    {
        get
        {
            return DataContext as MainViewModel;
        }
    }

    public GenerateView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Context.PropertyChanged += Context_PropertyChanged;
    }

    private void Context_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Action to perform
    }
}
```

The line `Context.PropertyChanged += Context_PropertyChanged;` throw an Exception because Datacontext is null.

Comment: DataContext is inherited down to all child controls if not set explicitly. Try removing it from your UserControls and only set it in the Window.

Comment: Also, the DataContext won't be set until after the constructor is called. Use the DataContextChanged event to know when it's set.

Comment: @Nudity I removed it from UserControls, and test. DataContext is null on constructor GenerateView, but after `InitializeComponent` from `MainViewModel`, DataContext is correct on both. But i'm unable to set `Context.PropertyChanged` on my UserControl

@Andrew Perfect !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the main requirement behind reusing a view model for Window and it’s sub user control?
it doesn’t make sense. Does both have everything in common?

In my opinion create a `MainWindowViewModel` and create `SubViewModel` for user control.
Create the instances of sub viewmodels in your MainWindowViewModel and access them using `DataContext.SubViewModel`.

By doing so, you could maintain the code and application well as well as preserve coding standards and have a complication free viewmodel. If you mix up everything just for reusability, you may be violating the MVVM pattern. Let different views/windows have its own viewmodel since they are not at all alike.

If both are alike, then you can create reusable controls using `Dependency Properties`.

Comment: My MainWindows is an empty windows. My application is use to generate or read images. I have one UserControl with IHM use to read(`ReadView`) and the other onr to generate (`GenerateView`). Both UserControls use the same fileds/properties and some common methods. I just started to design my application, I can change it. That's why I asked my question, I want to respect MVVM pattern and your answer seems very interesting. Is there a proper way to create something like : `MainWindowViewModel` with common fields/methods and  both `GenerateViewModel` and `ReadViewModel` inherited from main ?

Comment: @A.Pissicat: Yes. It's obviously possible. And that was what I was saying. You can have a parent view model. But you cannot inherit view models. Maybe if you have both views in common use dependency properties to have reusable views. So that you can update these properties when you want to change the data. Instead of having 2 views, you can use 1 view if all properties are same and change the data accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I usually set the `DataContext` in my `Window`:

```
public class MainWindow : Window
{
   InitializeComponent();
   ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();
   this.DataContext = vm;
}
```

or sometimes more advanced:

I add a static property to my ViewModel:

```
public static ViewModel Instance {get; set;}

public class MainWindow : Window
{
   InitializeComponent();
   if(ViewModel.Instance == null)
   {
       ViewModel.Instance = new ViewModel();           
   }
   this.DataContext = ViewModel.Instance;
}
```

Comment: I wonder if it is not easier to create the ViewModel as a Singleton ?

Comment: @A.Pissicat that depends on your usecase. I prefere using always the same instance and not creating a new VM every time. When it gets to alot of bindings I dont want to get all with default values - instead I get the values the VM had at last.

Answer (score 0):

According to Andrew's comment I'have the solution to my problem:

public partial class GenerateView : UserControl
{
    private MainViewModel Context
    {
        get
        {
            return DataContext as MainViewModel;
        }
    }

```
public GenerateView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContextChanged += GenerateView_DataContextChanged;
}

private void GenerateView_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Context != null)
        Context.PropertyChanged += Context_PropertyChanged;
}
private void Context_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //Action to perform
}
```

}

And I removed `DataContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type MyProject:MainWindow}}}"` from my UserControl.

Answer (score 0):

One can use the View first approach.
You first define a design context for design purposes.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.Views.CustomView"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
     xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject.Views"
     xmlns:p="clr-namespace:MyProject.Properties"
     xmlns:MyProject="clr-namespace:MyProject" 
     mc:Ignorable="d"
     d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=vm:MyViewModel}"
     d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
  <Grid>
     .....
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

then you bind the usercontrol to the datacontext of the mainwindow

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject"
    xmlns:v="clr-namespace:MyProject.Views"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MyProject" >
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MyViewModel/>        
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <v:CustomView/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

then the usercontrol will automatically inherit the datacontext of its parent.